# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it? while sending message from mvc

Tags: c#, email, smtp, mailmessage

I am trying to send a message from my website. This is working fine in my localhost but when i try to publish and host my code it is not running>

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(email, client_email);
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
mm.CC.Add("support@netripples.com");
mm.Subject = "Customer review from Netripples Website";
mm.Body = messagebody;

NetworkCred.UserName = email;
NetworkCred.Password = password;
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
smtp.Host = host;
smtp.Port = port;
smtp.Timeout = 500000;
smtp.Send(mm);
```

i expect to send the mail bu it is not sending . i am getting a error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it follewed by ip address and port number"

Comment: your port 25 is closed, please check firewall with your network team

Comment: Your local machine is able to reach the mail server on the specified `host` and `port`. Your production server is not able to reach the same mail server - are you using a debug mail server that is not on the same network as the production server? Are you using a mail server that has a firewall that prevents the production server reaching it? Is the production server running a firewall that blocks outbound connections to mail servers?

Comment: i have tried all the ports like 25,2525,587 @metal

Comment: using telnet [ip] 25

Comment: it says connection is successfull @metal

Answer (score 0):

Seems your smtp server ssl is enabled.

try adding.

```
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```